# Is it possible to call a FnOnce from a Fn without a Mutex?

Tags: rust

`Fn` can be sent via a channel, but `FnOnce` cannot yet on stable. In order to send a `FnOnce` through a channel it is possible to wrap it in a `Fn`, as shown below.

However, this requires a `Mutex`, which introduces an annoying overhead when scaling to very high throughput (i.e. tangibly, when you do this a lot, it's slow).

Is there some other concurrency primitive I could use here that would be less heavyweight? Perhaps with `std::sync::atomic`? Can this be done without a lock?

I have no interest in using nightly features or crates that rely on undefined behavior.

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::sync::mpsc;

struct RawFunc {
    data: Box<Fn() + Send + 'static>,
}

impl RawFunc {
    fn new<T>(inner: T) -> RawFunc
    where
        T: FnOnce() + Send + 'static,
    {
        let inner_lock = Mutex::new(Some(inner));
        return RawFunc {
            data: Box::new(move || match inner_lock.lock() {
                Ok(mut i) => (i.take().unwrap())(),
                Err(_) => {}
            }),
        };
    }

    fn invoke(self) {
        (self.data)()
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Local
    let x = RawFunc::new(move || {
        println!("Hello world");
    });
    x.invoke();

    // Via channel
    let (sx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<RawFunc>();
    sx.send(RawFunc::new(move || {
        println!("Hello world 2");
    })).unwrap();
    let output = rx.recv().unwrap();
    output.invoke();

    // In a thread
    let guard = thread::spawn(move || {
        let output = rx.recv().unwrap();
        output.invoke();
    });

    sx.send(RawFunc::new(move || {
        println!("Hello world 3!");
    })).unwrap();

    guard.join().unwrap();

    // Passing arbitrary data to a thread
    let (sx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<RawFunc>();
    let guard = thread::spawn(move || {
        let output = rx.recv().unwrap();
        output.invoke();
    });

    let bar = RawFunc::new(move || {
        println!("Moved func!");
    });
    let foo = String::from("Hello World 4");
    sx.send(RawFunc::new(move || {
        println!("Some moved data: {:?}", foo);
        bar.invoke();
    })).unwrap();

    guard.join().unwrap();
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a3d338835d0bcae646f46e3d982aca28&version=stable)

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/gyscos/Cursive/blob/master/src/cursive.rs#L18

Comment: @hellow that's perfect, thank you! Do you want to post that as an answer? I'll happily accept it. Seems to work just great, eg. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8e96ea704dbb48eb78dc1041dc509e2f&version=stable

Comment: Why do you use `Fn` instead of `FnMut`? https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=acd83291926a8d7e2b393be31b4b68a6&version=stable

Comment: You only need `Send` not `Sync`, so you can replace the `Mutex` with a `RefCell`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a3d338835d0bcae646f46e3d982aca28&version=stable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author of the [cursive crate](https://crates.io/crates/cursive) had exactly the same problem and solved it with their own trait.

```
/// Asynchronous callback function trait.
///
/// Every `FnOnce(&mut Cursive) -> () + Send` automatically
/// implements this.
///
/// This is a workaround only because `Box<FnOnce()>` is not
/// working and `FnBox` is unstable.
pub trait CbFunc: Send {
    /// Calls the function.
    fn call_box(self: Box<Self>, &mut Cursive);
}

impl<F: FnOnce(&mut Cursive) -> () + Send> CbFunc for F {
    fn call_box(self: Box<Self>, siv: &mut Cursive) {
        (*self)(siv)
    }
}
```

[source](https://github.com/gyscos/Cursive/blob/d52299a6e1fdc65d76105810653ed5340c3ad16f/src/cursive.rs#L17-L33)

[Here is the PR](https://github.com/gyscos/Cursive/pull/208), where the code was introduced.